# Remove padding from Material UI SwipeableViews React

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm having some trouble with the *Tabs/SwipeableViews* from React.
I copied this: [MaterialUI Tabs](https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/).
Which overall works fine! 
I just have a small issue with padding in the content.

**My result:**
[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF7dx.png)

Overall buttons work all fine and dandy, + the animation aswell. But when I inspect the page there is a 24px padding on the content (It was previously on the buttons aswell, I was able to fix this with just overriding the style. But the content of the *Swipeablev
**Wanted result:**
[Wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jhCX.png)

I've tried a few different things, even dirty tricks as doing -24px margin. But that broke the tabs.. Any help would be much appreciated and hopefully I gave enough information on the matter!

Have a nice day.

Comment: current result and wanted result are the exact same picture

Comment: and if you want to remove padding use inline styles and set padding to 0

Comment: @RobertTerrel Thank you very much for pointing that out! Stupid on my part. I've tried adding `style={{padding: 0}}` but no luck sadly. I've added (hopefully well) a codesandbox.io link where I attempted the inline styling. Would you be able to point me where I'm going wrong? [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-sky-m6dbl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <div
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`full-width-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`full-width-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && (
        <Box style={{ padding: 0 }} p={3}>
          <Typography>{children}</Typography>
        </Box>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

your issue was in the above function.  you needed to remove the padding from the Box within the TabPanel function.

I believe the issue was you were giving it the prop of p={3} which gives it default padding

Comment: Thank you very much! It was indeed the case. Can't believe I missed that.. Have a nice day!